# how to move the Laravel Bootstrap Cache Directory to other location

Tags: laravel

I cant' make the Laravel boostrap/cache folder writable for different reasons (system config), and I got this error:
"bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable"

Is there a way to move this folder to another place? I can't find a relevant setting.

Comment: can you change user of bootstrap/cache?

Comment: you mean webserver user?, no I can't . I cannot even access acc and prod server, I can only change .env configuration. There is cache directory that I can use but it is not clear to me how to write the boostrap cache to that directory too. it's Imho  funky to have different cache in different directories, why don't use storage/framework for boostrap cache too?

Answer (score 0):

The 'config:cache' location of Laravel can be changed by setting the `APP_CONFIG_CACHE` environment variable to a custom absolute path like:

```
APP_CONFIG_CACHE=/tmp/storage/bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

The directory must be present and writable.